# Validate JSON schema with other JSON schema in C#

Tags: c#, json, .net-core, jsonschema, json-schema-validator

I want to evaluate the json schema with another json schema. I am creating a form with the default json schema and adding some new properties. After that I am posting this new json schema. At this point I need to validate the new schema. Because I want to know that there are some properties in the new schema. I want to give an example

My default schema:

```
{
  "$schema": "https://json-schema.org/draft/2020-12/schema",
  "$id": "https://example.com/product.schema.json",
  "title": "Product",
  "description": "A product from Acme's catalog",
  "type": "object",
  "properties": {
    "productId": {
      "description": "The unique identifier for a product",
      "type": "integer"
    },
    "productName": {
      "description": "Name of the product",
      "type": "string"
    }
  },
  "required": [ "productId", "productName" ]
}
```

New successful schema:

```
{
  "$schema": "https://json-schema.org/draft/2020-12/schema",
  "$id": "https://example.com/product.schema.json",
  "title": "Product",
  "description": "A product from Acme's catalog",
  "type": "object",
  "properties": {
    "productId": {
      "description": "The unique identifier for a product",
      "type": "integer"
    },
    "productName": {
      "description": "Name of the product",
      "type": "string"
    },
    "productType": {
      "description": "Type of the product",
      "type": "string"
    },
    "categoryId": {
      "description": "Category id",
      "type": "integer"
    }
  },
  "required": [ "productId", "productName", "categoryId" ]
}
```

New error schema:

```
{
  "$schema": "https://json-schema.org/draft/2020-12/schema",
  "$id": "https://example.com/product.schema.json",
  "title": "Product",
  "description": "A product from Acme's catalog",
  "type": "object",
  "properties": {
    "productId": {
      "description": "The unique identifier for a product",
      "type": "integer"
    }
  },
  "required": [ "productId" ]
}
```

In a successful example, new properties with default properties were added. However, in the error example, the productName property, which should have been by default, has been removed. So how can I verify the schema with another schema?

Edit: @Relequestual fixed me. My question is how can I confirm my schema with meta-schema?

Comment: I'm unclear what it is you are asking here. Could you expand a little? Your phrasing means I can't understand your problem. I don't understand "verify the schema with another schema". This usually means confirming the Schema is valid using the meta-schema, but it doesn't look like this is what you mean, and I don't know how else to interpret what you've said. I think you need to explain more about what you mean by "I want to know that there are some features in the new schema"? I'm sorry, I want to help but currently I cannot.

Comment: @Relequestual 'confirming the Schema is valid using the meta-schema' is correct sentenc for my question. I have meta schema for confirm another schema. How can I confirm schema with meta-schema

Comment: There is a meta-schema which is used to validate a JSON Schema is valid. It exists. It sounds like you've created a schema to check something specific (I still don't understand what). A schema is still JSON, so just treat the schema you want to validate as just JSON.

Comment: If you simply want to validate that a JSON schema is, in fact, a valid JSON schema, you can use the meta-schemas at https://json-schema.org/specification.html

Comment: It sounds to me like you want to verify that a schema is a strict subset of another schema. I know of no tools designed for that purpose. I also don't see why you would want to do that. Your new schema can `$ref` the original schema and then add whatever new constraints you like.